# When someone clicks on the link on my site, I want the site they go to not to be seen as coming from my site

Tags: php, html

When someone clicks on the link on my site, I want the site they go to not to be seen as coming from my site.
Sample..

[www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) is my site. and I have such a link on my site.

```
<a href="www.someonessite.com">Someone's website</a>
```

When the visitor of my site clicks on this link, I want the outgoing site not to be seen as coming from my site.

Like in php. You can see where is visitor coming from by tis code `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` And i want to hide it or
I want it to look like he is coming from another site

annotation:
I cannot use link shortening systems. my site gets links from some sites in the form of bots and my visitors click on this link and go to that site

Answer (score 1):

You can add the meta referrer tag

```
<meta name="referrer" content="none">
```

or send the Referrer-Policy HTTP header

```
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
```

or put the `rel='noreferrer'` attribute on the `a` tag

```
<a href="www.someonessite.com" rel="noreferrer">Someone's website</a>
```